# Azure pipeline email notification on new test failures

Tags: azure-devops, outlook, automated-tests, azure-pipelines

I am in a situation where I want to notify the developers when there is a new change (new failure or new pass) in a test run from the previous test result. Is there any way to do this in Azure pipelines? I want to send the notification through email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such built-in diff-notification. Notifications are generally sent based on the result of a pipeline (pass/fail), not the actual results of sub-steps.

But... Test results are published to Azure DevOps and are accessible from the REST API. Technically it's possible to create a custom task that queries this job's test results and the previous job's test results, diffs them and then sends out an email by talking directly to an SMTP server, like Office 365's.